# Cast from int to String on android

Tags: string, int

I'm developing an app where I need to send the values of 3 seekbars via bluetooth. All the bluetooth method I've developed is based on the bluetoothChat example. The app communicates well sending characters, but as i said, i need to send the value of 3 seekbars.

So, I'm creating a sending function to send these 3 values in one string, but i think that i'm doing wrong the cast because i'm getting an error and the logcat refers my to this point.

This is the code, need to mention that the "savedProgressX" values are int type and have the current value of the seekbar, and the "sendX" values are textview type that I've created only to save these values:

```
public void sendValues() {

    send1 = Integer.toString(savedProgress1);
    send2 = Integer.toString(savedProgress2);
    send3 = Integer.toString(savedProgress3);

    /**Set the seekbars values into a string*/
    String message = send1+":"+send2+":"+send3+"\n";
    //String[] values = message.split(":");
    //for (String value : values) {
    //int number = Integer.valueOf(value);
    //}

    /**Check that we're actually connected before trying anything*/
    if (GlobalVar.mTransmission.getState() != GlobalVar.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    /**Get the message bytes and tell the Transmission to write*/
    byte[] send = message.getBytes();
    GlobalVar.mTransmission.write(send);

    /**Reset out string buffer to zero*/
    GlobalVar.mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting, and on which line?

Comment: Well, I just solved, it was a cast issue when trying to set the textview while i had not defined an id for it. Now, i need to include a carriage return at the end of the string. How is this done?

Comment: Why are you storing the Strings in TextViews? Why not store them in String variables? This line seems wrong - `String message = send1+":"+send2+":"+send3`. If you want to get the String values out of the TextViews, you need `String message = send1.getText().toString()+":"+send2.getText().toString()+":"+send3.getText().toString()`

Comment: Just edited the code before. How can I set the carriage return at the end of the string?